# How to eliminate the navigation bar on top of the page number in Latex Beamer in only ONE slide? (not the entire document)

Tags: latex, beamer

I would like to remove the navigation bar (containing circles and other things) from one of the slides of my presentation.

I read in this forum that by adding "\beamertemplatenavigationsymbolsempty" to the preamble. But this is not what I want! I want to only eliminate from one specific slide, not the entire document.

Any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Perhaps you are looking for something like this:

```
{
\usenavigationsymbolstemplate{}

%
% Place your slide code here
%

}
```